# Does Akismet plugin expose any hooks, functions, class that can work with custom code?

Tags: comments, akismet

I have custom code that handles comment insertions using `wp_insert_comment`. Does `Akismet plugin` expose any hooks, functions, class that can work with the same and possibly elsewhere where custom forms for user content submissions are involved? Or do I need to write custom code to make calls to Akismet API?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94947/check-spam-in-custom-form-akismet might answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I `grep`ed a slightly aging copy of the Akismet plugin and these are the hooks I found-- filters first, then actions.

```
admin.php:374:  if ( apply_filters( 'akismet_show_user_comments_approved', get_option('akismet_show_user_comments_approved') ) == 'true' ) {
akismet.php:144: $akismet_ua = apply_filters( 'akismet_ua', $akismet_ua );
akismet.php:201: if ( $incr = apply_filters('akismet_spam_count_incr', 1) )
akismet.php:336: $akismet_nonce_option = apply_filters( 'akismet_comment_nonce', get_option( 'akismet_comment_nonce' ) );
akismet.php:391: if ( $incr = apply_filters('akismet_spam_count_incr', 1) )
akismet.php:439: if ( apply_filters('akismet_optimize_table', ($n == 11)) ) // lucky number
akismet.php:448: $interval = apply_filters( 'akismet_delete_commentmeta_interval', 15 );
akismet.php:472: if ( apply_filters( 'akismet_optimize_table', ( $n == 11 ), 'commentmeta' ) ) { // lucky number 
akismet.php:586:$akismet_comment_nonce_option = apply_filters( 'akismet_comment_nonce', get_option( 'akismet_comment_nonce' ) );

admin.php:548:  do_action('akismet_submit_nonspam_comment', $comment_id, $response[1]);
admin.php:599:  do_action('akismet_submit_spam_comment', $comment_id, $response[1]);
admin.php:740:  do_action( 'comment_remove_author_url' );
admin.php:755:  do_action( 'comment_add_author_url' );
akismet.php:376: do_action( 'akismet_comment_check_response', $response );
akismet.php:383: do_action( 'akismet_spam_caught' );
akismet.php:434: do_action( 'delete_comment', $comment_ids );
legacy.php:85:   do_action( 'delete_comment', $comment_ids );
legacy.php:222:do_action( 'akismet_tabs' ); // so plugins can add more tabs easily
```

As you can see, a number of those specifically reference comments though I don't know exactly what you need to do. As far as other "user content submissions are involved", again, I don't know what exactly you need to do.

I would make a suggestion though. Rather than looking for hooks, which may or may not be present for what you need, look at the [various functions provided by the Akismet plugin](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/akismet/trunk/akismet.php). Some of those functions, for example `akismet_http_post()`, provide pretty convenient access to the Akismet API, at least that is how it looks to me.

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. After a lot of deliberation I think I would need to write to my own code for the functionality I need. The site I'm working on in addition to usual comments also allows user's to submit self-generate content via means of different forms. Akismet's functions within the plugin can be a starting point. Thanks for looking into this.